What motivated Karl Marx, on a personal level?
Why did Karl Marx care so much about there being inequality in society? Did he have personal experiences that aroused his compassion for the poor? Was he influenced by preexisting left-leaning politics that simply already advocated a change in social structures that led to more fairness and equality? Was there any personal reason he felt begrudged by the rich or the ruling powers? Was Marx motivated by dislike for authority, or genuine empathy for the poor?

Like other socialists i suppose he was motivated by the pretty horrible condition of the working class in Europe at the time.

Remember that Marx was a rich kid. Like Engels, Lenin, Trotsky, Keynes (yes, the economist), Chilean Allende, Ché Guevara, etc. to Justin Trudeau, Ocasio-Cortez, Bernstein (Germany SPD), France's Georges Sorel, Venezuela's Maduro, Spain Pablo Iglesias, Greece's Varoufakis, Argentina's Nestor and Cristina Kirchner, etc.

@RodolfoAP How is that relevant to my answer?

There are no straightforward answers here. Marx's influences are diverse and complicated. To find a full answer, I would recommend looking at one of the many biographies that discuss his life and his influences. The academic standard generally seems to be McLennan's book, while a more philosophical approach might be found in Berlin's text. I can also recommend Lenin's article on Marx (which is historically interesting if not as rigorous as the other two).
My own understanding is pedestrian but the broad story is something like this:  Marx was born in an upper-middle class family, but one that had only recently come into wealth. His father was a classical liberal. Marx was home-schooled by his liberal father, and then he joined a fairly liberal school run by one of his fathers' friends. By the time he got to University, he was already a fairly anti-conservative individual. He joined radical groups while at University, and attended lectures by Edward Gans. Gans himself used to be a student of Hegel, and that's probably where Marx picked up a lot of Hegelian ideas.
So, there probably isn't one 'inciting incident'. It is the political climate in Europe, the liberal nature of his family and education, the circles he socialised in as he grew (including his marriage to a member of petty nobility who herself broke off an engagement to an aristocrat to be with Marx, which was fairly controversial), and the ideas he was exposed to at University that came together to form the grounds on which he philosophised.
